# Are events more cache-friendly code than virtual/overriden methods in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, events, caching, virtual-functions

Reading about the [cache-friendly code in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699247/what-is-cache-friendly-code), I want to know if firing and handling events could be more cache-friendly than overriding methods when working with classes in C# (because one of the answers states that one should avoid virtual methods, at least in C++), or there is any better strategy than both approaches?

Comment: Try to understand *why* virtuals are not cache-friendly. Once you do, it should be obvious that events are even unfriendlier.

Comment: They solve entirely different problems.  I don't see how it's really comparable.  Perhaps you should show an example problem, and then solve it with both events and without events.  Then a comparison can be more meaningful.

Comment: @Servy, its because I have created a base Form class, which implements virtual methods, that are overriden in all the derived classes, but I was wondering if could be better to fire events implemented in derived classes rather than overriding methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to know if firing and handling events could be more cache-friendly than overriding methods when working with classes in C#

In general, no.  Events are going to require calling out to a separate class instance, which is going to be in a separate memory location.  This is going to have the same (or likely even worse) cache issues than virtual method calls.

> or there is any better strategy than both approaches?

Unfortunately, idiomatic C# tends to be non-cache friendly.  In order to write cache friendly C# code, you typically want to use `struct` over `class`, avoid virtual methods, avoid events, avoid delegates (at least ones with closures), etc.  Rico Mariani had a nice [blog post on Value based programming](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2006/08/31/733887.aspx) which discusses many of these issues in detail.