# Multithreading slower than singlethread in function with substantial memory access

Tags: c, pthreads

Is that a lot of memory access makes slow multithreading? Because I use pthread to multithread a great function who use a lot of memory access. And I have time CPU greater then if I call my function with 1 thread. And proportion of use CPUs is between 50% and 70%.

Comment: Yes may be, because of context switch time among threads, always give enough work to a thread, design in parallel programming is very important

Comment: Not every code is parallelliz... parall... threadable. It all depends on what you're actually doing inside.

Comment: Read about memory thrashing here: "[What is “cache-friendly” code?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16699282/335858)"

Comment: in the case of excessive crosstalk between threads, yes multithreading can be slower, at some level the code has to "synchronize" the memory between the various processes or threads.  In general, it takes planning to make efficient parallel code, not just breaking up an algorithm that was written for in-order processing

Comment: Try running the threads on a single core - if the performance is better than running the threads on multiple cores, this indicates cache bounce issues. If not, it indicates nothing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't guess; measure.

You don't say what OS you're using, but given pthreads I'm going to guess Linux. Use tools like Valgrind's `callgrind` and `cachegrind` to analyse where your program is spending its time. `LTTng` could also help you. Maybe `perf` also.

Yes, if your program is maxing out your memory bandwidth, or thrashing your cache, then multithreading could certainly slow down performance. This is especially true if the threads are trying to share any resources. BUT, you won't know if you don't look.

Answer (score 1):

Aside (since you seem to be talking about memory access and not allocation), the default `malloc` has poor performance if you are allocating memory in parallel.

If you are looking for higher performance you may want to consider [TCMalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) which scales significantly better with multithreaded allocations.

In general, keeping shared memory synchronised between threads is a nightmare that should probably be avoided if possible. See if you can avoid cache invalidations by adopting a message-passing paradigm (this may not be possible for your use-case).

Message passing with shared read-only memory is a good compromise for lowering cache traffic.