# Swig C++: Interfacing vector<Class object *>

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, swig

basically I am trying to have a tuple/list which contains a dictionary of different data types of values(float/int/bool/char/list) in python.

I am getting this from the following code:

```
(<f_p.Bunch; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'Bunch *' at 0x7f4954bdde10> >, <f_p.Bunch; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'Bunch *' at 0x7f4954bdde40> >, <f_p.Bunch; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'Bunch
*' at 0x7f495668be70> >, <f_p.Bunch; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'Bunch *' at 0x7f4952d09a50> >)
```

I want to get the output in this form:

> ({'I':1.0,'B':2.0, 'C':3.0, 'dert_':[1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6]})

I ain't able to deal with this class object pointer (bunch*) and couldn't find any solution to it. I looked on the net but couldn't found a working solution for my case.

**f_p.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "f_p.h"
#define CPP_14 0

std::vector<Bunch*> form_p(const double *array, int x, int y)  {

    std::vector<Bunch*> v;
    Bunch *b1 = new Bunch(5);
    b1->set_I_B_C(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
    b1->set_dert_({1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6});

    float *_dert = b1->get_dert_();
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        std::cout << _dert[i] << std::endl;
    }

    v.push_back(b1);
    v.push_back(b1); 
    v.push_back(b1); 
    v.push_back(b1); 

    return v;
}
```

**f_p.h:**

```
#ifndef F_P_H
#define f_P_H
#include <memory> 
#include <vector>
#include <memory> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <initializer_list>

class Bunch {
    private:
        unsigned int start;
        unsigned int end;
        float I;
        float B;
        float C;
        bool isPos;
        std::unique_ptr<float[]> dert_;
    public:

        explicit Bunch(size_t width) {
            #if CPP_14
            this->dert_ = std::make_unique<float[]>(width);
            #else
            this->dert_ = std::unique_ptr<float[]>(new float[width]);
            #endif
            std::fill_n(this->dert_.get(), width, -1.0);
        }

        void set_I_B_C(float I, float B, float C) {
            this->I = I;
            this->B = B;
            this->C = C;
        }

        std::tuple<float, float, float> get_I_B_C() const {
            return std::make_tuple(this->I, this->B, this->C);
        }

        float* get_dert_() const {
            return this->dert_.get();
        }

        void set_dert_(std::initializer_list<float> l) {
            int i = 0;
            for (auto e: l){
                dert_[i++] = e;
            }
        }
};
/* Define function prototype */
std::vector<Bunch*> form_p(const double *array, int x, int y)  ;
#endif
```

**f_p.i:**

```
%module f_p
#define SWIGPYTHON_BUILTIN

%{
  #include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
  #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT  /* To import_array() below */
  #include "f_p.h"
%}
%include "std_map.i"
%import "std_deque.i" 
%import "std_vector.i" 

%template (mapiv) std::map<char,float>;
%template () std::vector<Bunch*>;
%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
import_array();
%}

%apply (double* IN_ARRAY2, int DIM1, int DIM2) {
  (const double* array, int x, int y)
}

%include "f_p.h"
```

**build.sh:**

```
rm *.o f_p_wrap.cpp _f_p.so f_p.py
rm -rf __pycache__

g++ -O3 -march=native -fPIC -c f_p.cpp
swig -python -c++ -o f_p_wrap.cpp f_p.i

# Next, compile the wrapper code:

g++ -O3 -march=native -w -fPIC -c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs python3) -I /home/antpc/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include f_p.cpp f_p_wrap.cpp

g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -march=native -shared f_p.o f_p_wrap.o -o _f_p.so -lm
```

**test_sample.py:**

```
from f_p import form_p
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randn(3, 4)
print(form_p(x))
```

Comment: I modified my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59712985/how-to-make-a-stdmap-to-hold-different-data-types-in-swig to work for different data types. BUt now not able to interface it.

Comment: It looks like you just want to create an `typemap(out)` for `Bunch`. Why does `form_p` return `std::vector<Bunch *>` instead of `std::vector<Bunch>`? Swig isn't going to free those pointers so you're leaking memory.

Comment: If an answer helped in solving your problem then don't let the bounty go to waste

Comment: @Kerndog73: I wasn't aware it awards only 50% of the bounty when not chosen and rest is gone wasted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question really boils down to this: you have a class and you'd like to convert it a native Python object (rather than a wrapped object). SWIG automatically generates wrapped objects but you have to go out of your way to convert C++ types to native Python types.

---

I'm assuming this simplified `Bunch` to make the typemap a little more readable. You should be able to adapt this to your `Bunch` quite easily. Alternatively, you could convert your class to this simple struct before passing it on to Python.

```
struct Bunch {
    float i, b, c;
    std::vector<float> dert;
};

Bunch makeBunch();
```

Here's the implementation of `makeBunch`.

```
Bunch makeBunch() {
    return {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, {1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6}};
}
```

I've omitted error checking to keep it short and concise.

```
%typemap(out) Bunch {
    $result = PyDict_New();
    PyDict_SetItem($result, PyBytes_FromString("I"), PyFloat_FromDouble($1.i));
    PyDict_SetItem($result, PyBytes_FromString("B"), PyFloat_FromDouble($1.b));
    PyDict_SetItem($result, PyBytes_FromString("C"), PyFloat_FromDouble($1.c));
    PyObject *dert = PyList_New($1.dert.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i != $1.dert.size(); ++i) {
        PyList_SetItem(dert, i, PyFloat_FromDouble($1.dert[i]));
    }
    PyDict_SetItem($result, PyBytes_FromString("dert_"), dert);
}
```

When I compile and run this myself, I get the expected results (well, close enough!).

```
>>> import test
>>> test.makeBunch()
{'I': 1.0, 'C': 3.0, 'B': 2.0, 'dert_': [1.2000000476837158, 2.299999952316284, 3.4000000953674316, 4.5, 5.599999904632568]}
```

---

The typemap isn't strictly necessary. You can instead just use wrapped objects. Remove the type map and make sure to expose `std::vector<float>` like so.

```
%include "std_vector.i"
%template(FloatVector) std::vector<float>;
```

Then you can access `Bunch` via a wrapped object.

```
>>> import test
>>> bunch = test.makeBunch()
>>> bunch
<test.Bunch; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'Bunch *' at 0x10b6daba0> >
>>> bunch.i
1.0
>>> bunch.b
2.0
>>> bunch.c
3.0
>>> bunch.dert
<test.FloatVector; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::vector< float,std::allocator< float > > *' at 0x10b6dadb0> >
>>> for d in bunch.dert:
...     print(d)
...
1.20000004768
2.29999995232
3.40000009537
4.5
5.59999990463
```

---

Some reputable sources:

- [Typemaps](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn10)
- [PyDict](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/dict.html)
- [PyBytes](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytes.html)
- [PyFloat](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/float.html)
- [PyList](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/list.html)

Comment: Can you answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59712985/how-to-make-a-stdmap-to-hold-different-data-types-in-swig the answer for that is also the same as this one. I want to close that question.

Comment: @ninjakx If you want to close that question then just close it (or delete it).