# binary comparison not defined when using map<any,any>

Tags: c++, stdmap, stdany

I was looking for a way to have a `string[]` as a map value, and I found [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50956105/14257302). I attempted to use the `std::any` type to solve my problem, and I got the error

> binary '<': 'const _Ty' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <any>
using namespace std;
map<any,any> dat;
int main()
{
    any s[] = {"a","b"};
    dat["text"] = s;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::map` by default requires that the key type be comparable with `<`. `std::any` does not define any `operator<` and can therefore not be used as key in the map by default.

If you really want to use it in the map as a key, you need to implement your own comparator, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733254/how-can-i-create-my-own-comparator-for-a-map).

However, the comparator needs to define a weak strict order. It is probably not going to be easy to define that for `std::any`.

---

It is unlikely that `map<any,any>` is the correct approach to whatever problem you are trying to solve.

If you want a `std::string` array as key or value type, then use `std::array<std::string, N>` or `std::vector<std::string>` instead of a plain `std::string[N]`.

The `std::map` will work with these types out-of-the-box.

`std::any` has only very few use cases. If you don't have a very specific reason to use it, you probably shouldn't try to use it.