# How could I get a C++ std::map to have multiple values

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap

I'm trying to make a JSON parser in C++ and I need to get the std::map function to store any value, such as a bool, string, int, etc.

This is my (unfinished) code:

```
//stringX is a separate namespace that has only two functions (replace, and replace_all)
namespace json {
    void parse(std::string json) {
        stringX::replace_all(json, "{", "");
        stringX::replace_all(json, "}", "");
        size_t pos = 0;
        while ((pos = json.find(',', pos)) != std::string::npos) {
            if (json[pos + 1] == '"') {
                stringX::replace(json, ",", "\n", pos);
            }
            pos++;
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
std::map<std::string,(insert something here)> testMap;

testMap["first"] = true;
testMap["second"] = 1;
testMap["third"] = "hi!";
```

This doesn't work, since no type like this exists in C++. I could do this:

```
#include <any>

int main(){
    std::map<std::string, std::any> testMap;
    return 0;
}
```

but apparently "any" is undefined, so I tried the variant library instead:

```
#include <variant>

int main(){
    std::map<std::string, std::variant<(insert example types here)>> testMap;
    return 0;
}
```

Guess what? VARIANT is undefined too, so I resorted to StackOverflow. I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702235/c-stdmap-holding-any-type-of-value) that had exactly what I was looking for - but I couldn't really understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24702596/20940328) since I'm relatively new to C++: so I didn't really use that.

Any ideas on how I could do this? Also, *please* explain the concept to me if you have an answer.

Comment: Both `std::variant` and `std::any` require C++17 - are you sure you have enabled that (and your compiler supports it) when compiling?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: If you dont want to use variant, maybe you can add more assignment constructors, 1 per type. If map lets this happen.

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm using visual studio

Comment: Is there a reason you are making a parser by yourself? There is an excellent json parser library out there.

Comment: @Ult.ChadusSussusmanAmogus: which version of visual studio? I suspect you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308933/how-to-enable-c17-compiling-in-visual-studio

Comment: The default of Visual Studio 2015 though 2022 is c++14. I believe. Also many people call VSCode, Visual Studio because of the unfortunate naming that Microsoft used. VSCode is very different from Visual Studio Community / Enterprise / Pro. The instructions for VSCode are different.

Comment: https://ideone.com/BA6SCk is for storing python types, if you're the same use from earlier

Comment: I would avoid the `std::any` and create a `JsonObject` class that can represent any type of object that can be in the `JSON`.

Comment: @MartinYork Okay, I'll try that too. Thanks!