# How to access to the index of a 2D vector by at() function?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I am going to initialize a 2D vector in a member function, where the input arguments are planned to be fed into determined indexes within the function argument.
Furthermore, I'm not gonna use [] operator to member access due to safety stuffs.
How can I use at() function in order to access to the index of a 2D vector, as below?

```
vector<vector<double>> weight;

void Connection::setWeight(const double& value, const double& i, const double& j)
{
    // The other scheme except: weight[i][j] = value;
}
```

Comment: `weight.at(i).at(j) = value;`

Comment: +1 - I don't see why that question deserves a downvote.

Comment: @MaxBeikirch because it is trivial to figure this out by looking at some documentation?

Comment: @jaunchopanza: Maybe you don't believe me, but I asked this question up here after some time browsing the web to find it for more than one dimension... But thank you for your clarification upon the potential capabilities of the documentation!!!

Comment: Vectors never have more than one dimension. You need to think in terms of "chains of custody"; you get the inner vector from the outer vector then perform a new operation on that inner vector.

Comment: @matinking A vector of vectors is just a vector. But you could try to figure it out by looking at what `operator[]` does.

Comment: @matinking: Please do not approve edits that obviously do not add anything at all to the post.

Comment: @Ondkloss: As above.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `at` twice. Also note, if `i` and `j` are indexes, they really shouldn't be `double`.

```
void Connection::setWeight(const double value, const size_t i, const size_t j)
{
    weight.at(i).at(j) = value;
}
```

Comment: You mean they should integer, just like the intrinsic nature of the index type, right?

Comment: `size_t` is actually `unsigned int`, since you cannot use a negative index.

Answer (score 11):

<sub>Risking to be downvoted for [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization), and because it doesn't really answers the question asked,  still I would like to remind about a serious problem in such approach.</sub>

Like any multidimensional array, vector of vector is not contiguous, which makes its performance characteristics terribly bad because of lacking of [spatial locality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) and associated [cache misses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_miss).

You can trivially solve the problem by wrapping a single-dimensional array with a convenient interface of two-dimensional array.

```
template <class T>
class MyArray2D
{
    std::vector<T> data;
    size_t sizeX, sizeY;
public:

const T& at(int x, int y) const { return data.at(y + x * sizeY); }

T& at(int x, int y) { return data.at(y + x * sizeY); }

// wrap other methods you need of std::vector here
};
```

Note that code above written on the fly and wasn't compiled. Still, I believe you've got the idea.

See also:

- [What is cache friendly code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699247).
- [Spatial Locality of Reference: an Efficient Access Pattern in any Cache System](http://www.tophatstuff.co.uk/archive.php?p=119)

Comment: _"Risking to be downvoted for premature optimization, ..."_ Well I give you an initial charge ;). Your points are valid and relevant.

Comment: @Drop: You asserted that the performance in this case is terrible... So what is your suggestion for a efficient data structure for linear algebra and matrix manipulation?! Could you please explain that why your snippet might be better than 2D vectors, in view of the performance?

Comment: @matinking Well, that "terrible performance" is actually a bad and unprofessional way of describing my subjective understanding of how multidimensional arrays work. Surely you need to profile and think in a context of your application. Maybe vector of vectors will work just fine for you and you need no introduce additional complexity in your code. But, as a starting point I would advise to try to make a such a custom wrapper to `std:vector` and compare its performance to original approach. Also, me personally find it helpful in many applications, from tetris grid ;) to complex math apps.

Comment: @matinking CPU cache is very important in our days so we must not throw away any possibility to abuse it (along with multithreading, vectorization and branch prediction). There are very good explanations given if you follow the "See also" links, so I would not like to repeat it. (And I am probably not able to explain it better)

Comment: @Drop: +1 for the clearance and the resources :D, even though I still can't consider the other approach for my case!...