# For-loop variables and cache misses?

Tags: c++, for-loop, caching, optimization

The default way of using for loops which is taught in most cases looks something like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 32; y++)
    {
        level[x][y].update();
    }
}
```

But some people insist that swapping the x and y order in the for loop increases performance. I suspect that this is because of cache misses?

```
for (int y = 0; y < 32; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++)
    {
        level[x][y].update();
    }
}
```

Can anybody explain if this is correct and if so, WHY does it help?
If not, what is the reason?

Comment: I think the swap can only decrease performance on catch, since `level[x][0]` and `level[x][1]` are closer than `level[0][x]` and `level[1][x]`

Comment: Does this remarkable Q&A answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699247/what-is-cache-friendly-code/16699282#16699282

Comment: This is a classic example for cache miss. I'm wondering why you see the code without explanation.

Comment: `level[x][y]` is somewhat unusual (array-of-columns layout) and then you *would* want the y-loop to be the inner most loop.