# How to count all paths from a point to another point in 3d grid with conditions

Tags: c++, algorithm, path, point

Given the input *xm, ym,h* I have to find all paths from point (1,0,1) to (xm, ym, 1) in a 3d grid such as:

1. possible moves from (x,y,z) are (x+1, y, z), (x+1, y+1, z), (x+1, y-1, z)
2. if z < h more possible moves are (x+1, y, z+1), (x+1, y+1, z+1), (x+1, y-1, z+1)
3. if z > 1 more possible moves are also (x+1, y, z-1), (x+1, y+1, z-1),(x+1, y-1, z-1)

I figured out an algorithm that works for z = 1, but I am not sure how to make it work for other values of z. Any assistance will be appreciated.

```
llong countPaths3(int xm, int ym, int h) {
    std::pair<int,int> pair1 = {1,0};
    std::map<std::pair<int,int>, llong> map1;
    map1.insert({pair,1});
    int starty = -1;
    int endy = 1;
    llong value = 0;
        for(int x = 2; x <= xm; x++) {
            for(int y = starty; y <= endy; y++)
            {
                if (map1.count({x, y}) == 0) {
                    value = map1[{x - 1, y}] + map1[{x - 1, y + 1}] + map1[{x - 1, y - 1}];
                }

                map1[{x, y}] = value;
            }
            starty--;
            endy++;
        }
        return map1[{xm,ym}];
}
```

Comment: permutation count seems enough.

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: Path length is `xm`. y/z are unrelated so you can multiplies numbers of ways to go from y0-ym and z0-zm.

Comment: My idea was to count permutation of `n1 + ym` incrementation, `n1` decrementation, and `xm - 2 * n1` "noop". so IIRC, `(xm!)/(n1!*(n1+ym)!*(xm - 2 * n1)!`.

Comment: what does n1 stand for?

Comment: Number of decrement (considered) :), As example, to go from 0 to 3 in 5 step, we have `[(3+, 2=, 0-), (4+, 0=, 1-)]` first case `n1=0`, second case `n1=1`. First case has 10 (`5!/(3!*2!*0!)`) permutations, second case has 5 (`5!/(4!*0!*1!)`) permutations, so a total of 15 ways. whereas it should work for unbounded `y`, `z` seems more complicated...

Comment: @Jarod42 How can you deal with decreasing lower than 0?

Comment: @Jarod42 I used that y/z are unrelated so I multiplied the numbers of ways, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While this problem can be solved combinatorially it can also be solved using [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), with a time and memory complexity of `O(xm * ym * h)`.

Consider a 3d array where each point at index `i, j, k` in array represents the number of ways to get from `(1, 0, 1)` to `(i, j, k)`, we would like to find the value at the index `(xm, ym, 1)`.

We need to start filling the array,
First fill the `x = 1` layer, there are 0 ways to get everywhere except for `(1, 0, 1)` which has the value of 1.
Second fill the `x = 2` layer, there are 0 ways to get everywhere except for `(2, 0, 1)`, `(2, 1, 1)`, `(2, 0, 2)` which has the value of 1.
Than fill the next layer, and the one above it and so on until you reach the `xm`th layer - at this point you are done.
The general formula to fill up the index `(i, j, k)` is:

```
A[i, j, k] = 
A[i-1, j-1, k-1] + A[i-1, j-1, k-1] + A[i-1, j-1, k-1] + 
A[i-1, j, k]     + A[i-1, j, k]     + A[i-1, j, k]     + 
A[i-1, j+1, k+1] + A[i-1, j+1, k]   + A[i-1, j+1, k+1]
```

As mentioned - filling up the array using this formula takes time and memory complexity of `O(xm * ym * h)`.

Don't forget to check edge cases and fill the first layer manually.

Good luck.

Comment: Some technical note: Which index represents the x layer is important in order to fully [utilize the cache of the computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699247/what-is-a-cache-friendly-code).

Comment: I thought about something like that but for x = 2 I get (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 1), (2, -1, 1). How can I deal with the negative value?

Comment: "Don't forget to check edge cases" Check for `y` and `z` out of range, if it is than remove the invalid element from the sum.

Comment: for  xm = 3, ym = 0, h = 1 (3,0,1) I should get answer 3 - it can be derived from (2,0,1), (2,1,1) and (2,-1,1) so (2,-1,1) should be counted.

Comment: Oh sorry now I understand what you are saying... It is a bit more difficult to handle now but nothing too serious, the `y` dimension should actually be at the size of `2 * xm` where the first `xm` are negative values and the right ones are positive.