# Does cache align improve performance?

Tags: caching

In our system, I try to modify all the main data structure with

```
__attribute__((__aligned__(CACHE_LINE_SIZE)))
```

It does not improve any performance actually. How can we use cache align and measure how it helps?

Comment: I assume this is C(++)? Can you tag with the correct language please? You might also be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469427/how-and-when-to-align-to-cache-line-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache aligning only improves performance if the data is false shared across threads. what does that mean? If you have 2 fields, one of them shared and updated frequently, and one not, and they are in the same cache line then accessing the 'cold' field (the one not frequently updated) imposes the same penalty as accessing the 'hot' one, because updates of the 'hot' field invalidate other threads (CPU threads) entire cache line, thus invalidating the 'cold' field too. A similar case is when two 'hot' fields share the cache line and invalidate each other.

For other cases, cache align does not improve performance and may in fact hurt performance by increasing data size.

To consider cache align you need:

- concurrency
- hot data (frequent InterlockCompareExchange or similar ops)
- some other data in the cache line (hot or cold, depends on the use case)

I recommend Scott Meyer's talk [CPU Caches and Why You Care](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/home/cpu-caches-and-why-you-care).