# how to put two class members in the same cache line?

Tags: c++, caching, padding, memory-alignment

This question is inspired by an older question https://stackoverflow.com/a/8469621/14064670. In this link, @Phil Miller mentioned that the padding in the beginning will guarantee that the first two members end up in the same cacheline, but I cannot understand it. Can someone expain this?

> The padding at the beginning means that buffer_ and buffer_mask_ end up on the same cache line, rather than split across two lines and thus requiring double the memory traffic to access.

In my opinion, When two members are in the beginning, either __attribute__ or memalign() can help, but what about if these two members are in the middle of a struct?

Comment: Read the comments to that answer. The padding only prevents false sharing. The padding at the beginning prevents false sharing with adjacent variables. It doesn’t actually make `buffer_` and `buffer_mask_` share a cache line.

Answer (score 0):

The quote you're asking about simply isn't true in general. This was also pointed out in a very popular comment in the post:

> Actually, there is no assumption that "cacheline_pad_t will itself be aligned to a 64 byte;" alignment is actually not required. The padding just guarantees the only goal, namely that the variables before and after are in different cache lines.

In other words, the focus of the optimization is purely about cache line separation for variables declared between the padding. Nothing in the compiler/linker/runtime is going to guarantee that `buffer_` and `buffer_mask_` are given addresses within a single line.

**That said**, in practice, they probably will be. At least in the snippet shown, the first three variables declared are: `pad0_` (64 bytes), `buffer_` (pointer size, probably 8 bytes, arch dependent), and `buffer_mask_` (probably 8 bytes, arch dependent). All three of these are going to be placed in the `.bss` section.

When this module is loaded into memory on pretty much any common runtime system, the `.bss` section will be placed on a page boundary, because that's the standard unit of memory in an MMU-managed system. Page sizes are usually 4k minimum, cache lines are typically (but not required to be) 64 bytes, so aligning to a page, means you are also aligned to a cache line. So then `pad0_` will be page aligned, it will occupy one full cache line, which means `buffer_` starts a new cache line, and only occupies 8 bytes of it, which puts `buffer_mask_` immediately after it in the same line.

I'll reemphasize here: none of this is *guaranteed* to happen, it's just likely based on the most common toolchain + runtime behavior.

To your second questions:

> In my opinion, When two members are in the beginning, either **attribute** or memalign() can help, but what about if these two members are in the middle of a struct?

My best suggestion here would be to take advantage of the C/C++ guarantees on struct standard layout, meaning fields you declare in a struct are guaranteed to be placed in the order that you declared them. Thus if you want fields in the middle of a struct to be aligned in a particular way, you need to pad them manually to force alignment. Just be aware that different architectures do have different cache line sizes, so in general this will not be portable. For example:

```
// not cache optimized:
struct CacheNonOpt {
    uint32_t someArray1[12]; // 48 bytes
    uint32_t someArray2[12]; // 48 bytes
} myNonOptStruct;

// probably cache optimized, assuming you align it:
struct CacheNonOpt {
    uint32_t someArray1[12]; // 48 bytes
    uint32_t pad[4]; // 16 bytes
    uint32_t someArray2[12]; // 48 bytes
} myOptStruct;
```